# Using COUNTIFS with a range as criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have a situation where in I have to use COUNTIFS(range1, Criteria1, Range2, Criteria2...), where criteria should be a range in the same excel that has text in it. Is there a way for that?
My actual situation is 
Sheet 1 : col A and Col B - Text values
Sheet 2 : Col C and Col D - Text values

For every value in Col A, check if it is there in Col C, the take the corresponding value from Col D and check if it is the same in Col B. I need the count of how many matches or doesn't match. I tried to use Vlookup on this, but couldn't get what I wanted. I appreciate your suggestions on this.

Thanks,
Ramya

Comment: Application Defect  SpecialApp AllowedDefect    
App 1 Defect 5  App 1 Defect 5    
App 2 Defect 7  App 3 Defect 5    
App 3 Defect 5  App 5 Defect 3    
App 4 Defect 2  App 4  Defect 2    
App 5 Defect 1       
       Total Apps that match 3

Comment: Cross-posted here http://www.excelforum.com/excel-formulas-and-functions/1064669-countifs-having-a-range-as-criteria.html

Comment: @pnuts: can you email me at ramyacs.89@gmail.com, so that I could send you a sample file/ screenshot?

Comment: So, I used a sumproduct on the countif as suggested by someone and it did the trick =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS(A:A,D:D,B:B,E:E )). Now I can get what I needed. Thanks all for trying to help me :-)

Answer (score 0):

The example uses a Named Table.

`{=COUNT(IF(([@ColA]=[@ColC])*([@ColD]=[@ColB]),1))}`

[`COUNT`](https://support.office.microsoft.com/en-ca/article/COUNT-function-47858132-8828-4041-8c5b-a5fb729bab6f?CorrelationId=d5e2c54a-0c9f-4c34-8a98-d05ba2d627b5&ui=en-US&rs=en-CA&ad=CA) method counts the number of values.

`([@ColA]=[@ColC])*([@ColD]=[@ColB])` compares the current row's `Column A` value against `Column C` value, then returns `True`/`False` then the same thing for `Column D` value against `Column B` value, and multiplies them together to get:

`True`

- from `True` * `True`

or

`False`

- from `True` * `False` or `False * True` or `False *`False`)

And when the `IF` statement is `True`, it returns `1` to be used in the `COUNT`.

You can use an Array Formula to calculate whether a specific row in a table matches your criteria, then add the ones that do match up.

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> to create the Array Formula.

Comment: Cool! But here, there is a link between Column C and D. If there is a value in col A, find the same value in col C, if it is there, take the RESPECTIVE value in Col D and then Match it with the RESPECTIVE col B value that is next to that Col A value and see if it matches

Comment: @user1806980, the only way to do that efficiently would be to write a VBA macro to handle that. i.e. `Col E = FindMatch([@ColA],B:D)` where the `[@ColA]` is the value, then you give the `B:B`, `C:C`, `D:D` to find the row that matches.